# Given epimorphism $\phi$ and ideal $I$, with $\operatorname{Ker}\phi \subseteq I$, prove $\phi(\sqrt{I}) = \sqrt{\phi(I)}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I had this question on my exam.

> Let $\phi: R\to S$ be epimorphism (Homomorphism and onto). Prove if $I$ is an ideal of $R$ with $\operatorname{Ker}\phi \subseteq I$, then $\phi(\sqrt I) = \sqrt{\phi(I)}$.

I could show $\phi(\sqrt I)⊆ \sqrt{\phi(I)}$. How to show the converse?

Comment: Which definition of "radical" do you want to use? Nilpotent elements? or intersection of primes?

Comment: Nilpotent elements please

Comment: Put that in your post. Comments are more transitory, and this is an important piece of context.

Comment: Note that the question as stated is giving an incorrect definition of epimorphism - in general, an epimorphism of rings doesn't have to be onto.  (For example, the inclusion $\mathbb{Z} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ is an epimorphism in the category of rings, or in the category of commutative rings.)

Comment: @DanielSchepler That was the definition given in our class.. maybe because we consider the commutative rings only

Comment: @rschwieb I will , thank you !

Comment: Even if you consider commutative rings only, $\mathbb{Z} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ is still an epimorphism (in the sense that most mathematicians will understand the term).

Comment: Oh I see.. I guess I have to study more about this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $\;s\in\sqrt{\phi(I)}\;$ , which means that for some $\;n\in\Bbb N\;,\;\;s^n\in\phi(I)\;$ , thus:

$$\exists\,r\in I\,\,s.t.\;\;\phi r=s^n$$ .

Let now $\;t\in R\;$ be such that $\;\phi t=s\implies \phi(t^n)=s^n=\phi r\implies \phi(t^n-r)=0\implies\;$

$$t^n-r\in\ker\phi\subset I\implies \exists i\in I\;\;s.t.\;\;t^n-r=i\implies t^n=r+i\in I+I=I$$

End the proof now.

Comment: The proof I needed! Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

In general, if $\phi\colon R\to S$ is a ring homomorphism and $J$ is an ideal of $S$, we have an induced *injective* ring homomorphism $\psi\colon R/\phi^{-1}(J)\to S/J$, defined by $\psi(r+\phi^{-1}(J))=\phi(r)+J$.

If $\phi$ is also surjective, then $\psi$ is an isomorphism.

In your case, taking $J=\phi(I)$, we have $\phi^{-1}(J)=\phi^{-1}(\phi(I))=I+\ker\phi=I$. Therefore $\psi\colon R/I\to S/\phi(I)$ is an isomorphism.

Can you finish? Hint: $r\in\sqrt{I}$ if and only if $r+I$ is nilpotent in $R/I$.

Comment: Yes I can , thank you so much!